# Does CURL GET recipient see the file making the GET request?

Tags: php, curl, get, request-headers

Assuming we have File /path/*aFile.php*  which has a curl GET call to the domain example.com (example.com is a domain outside the local network).

```
$url="https://example.com/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
print $result;
```

Will the host of example.com see that the GET curl request came from the file "*aFile.php*"?
Will he be able to see more info like the directory of the file like "*/path/aFile.php*"

What info is shown? I tried using Charles app, and Tamper data and in the GET request it shows:

```
GET /path/aFile.php HTTP/1.1
```

If indeed such info is passed on to the receiver of the GET request, is it possible to not show all this info?

I have added in my curl request the following headers but I still get the same info.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   "Host:             example.com",
   "Accept-Encoding:  gzip",
   "Accept:           application/json",
   "Referer:          $hosturl_stripped",
   "User-Agent:       Mozilla/4.0 Firefox/46.0",
   "Accept-Language:  en-US,en;q=0.5",
   "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
));
```

Comment: You could curl a a php file, `print_r($_SERVER)` and find out. No, it is not visible unless you make it so. Why are you asking? That's probably more relevant.

Comment: I do not want to test it on a local environment, as I assume it could behave differently. I would not like someone to know the filename or folder structure of the file I am curling with on their website.

Comment: `I assume it could behave differently` It won't, but not trying at all is somewhat lazy. `I do not want them to know the name of the file` + `downloads/scrapes` - this alone makes it sound like you're doing something that doesn't deserve any help btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GET` request is just type of HTTP request, without any strings attached to any client software executing the call (be it browser, curl, wget whatever). But if you want you can however announce that by sending additional headers (i.e. `User-Agent`) along your request, as browsers (and curl by default too) do.

Comment: Will the receiving side know the file on my local computer which is making the GET request? I am downloading a webpage and I do not want them to know the name of the file I am using to do the php curl get.

Comment: You mean you got `foo.php` script that does the request and you want them to not know that? Such information is not part of HTTP request so other side will not know anything like that unless you send it in headers.

Comment: Yes, I am using a file in the folder /path/aFile.php which inside it is a cURL command which "downloads/scrapes" a webpage. Will they see the request coming from my IP or also from the file making that request?
While I use tamper-data addon and Charles proxy I see that that there is a field "GET /path/aFile.php HTTP/1.1

Comment: Of course there's `/path/aFile.php` because this is the file on the **remote server** YOU want to fetch. There's no way to not tell the server what you want it to serve and make it serve that anyway :) This is NOT a name of your script.

Comment: AFAIK "GET /path/aFile.php HTTP/1.1" means "Get file /path/aFile.php over HTTP/1.1 protocol"

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I think I figured out why I got the GET /path/aFile.php as I was using a proxy app to intercept and inspect the connection between the file. 
The proxy app was GETing the file and then forwarding thats why I saw the GET request. Does this seem reasonable to you?